# Shell script/linux command for altering Text files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

i have some 40000 of .txt files which contains frames like:

`30724 64260 65286 65527 46579 83 65 72 28652 65516 57343 3127 2067 30750 64332 65532 65532 38364 0 0 512 16368 65535 65534 55806 0 0 0 32271 .`

i just want to add some parameter name at start and end of the file so that i can use those files for my load Test.

the required format should be :

```
{
  "frames":"30724 64260 65286 65527 46579 83 65 72 28652 65516 57343 3127 2067 30750 64332 65532 65532 38364 0 0 512 16368 65535 65534 55806 0 0 0 32271",
  "params": {"rms":false,"removeSpecialFrames":"true"}
}
```

please help with linux scripts for do so as i am a beginner for shell scripts.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you done that's not producing correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^/{"frames":"/' -e 's/$/", "params": {"rms":false,"removeSpecialFrames":"true"}}/' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks anubhava for quick reply.
it worked exactly as i wanted.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. If you're satisfied you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p out
for f in *.txt; do
    echo '{"frames":"' > "out/$f"
    cat "$f" >> "out/$f"
    echo '", "params": {"rms":false,"removeSpecialFrames":"true"}}' >> "out/$f"
done
```

The above assumes you are in the directory full of *.txt files, and it will write the output to a new directory called "out".